# Add reference to Common project Azure DevOps Build Pipeline

Tags: .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I currently have a Web App project that references a Common project. Whenever I create a build pipeline for the Web App project I get the following error:

[image]

How do I go about adding the Common project to the Web App build pipeline so that this error does not occur?

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Hi Leo, I found my issue was that I had the two projects in separate repos, I restructured everything and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the cause of my issue.

I had the two projects in separate repos when they should have been inside one. After restructuring everything works correctly.

Comment: You've found a a work-around it get rid of the error. It's normal to have a library class in a separate repo as other project can reference that project. How would you reference that repo from another repo? I'd be curios to know.

Comment: @Programmer Referencing external projects as a Nuget package is the easier way to go.

Answer (score 0):

> Add reference to Common project Azure DevOps Build Pipeline

If the `Web App project` and `Common project` are in the same solution, you need to check if the relative path of `Common project` in the `Web App project` project file is correct:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Commonproject\Commonproject.csproj">
    ...
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Make sure the relative path matches the actual location of `Common project` project file.

If the `Web App project` and `Common project` are **not** in the same solution, you can try following methods:

- Add the .dll file of dependent project to a the NuGet package. upload
  to a feed, such as VSTS feed: [Package Management in VSTS and TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/overview?view=azure-devops),
  then restore packages during the build (This is the way we are
  using).
- Build the `Common project` project first, then add [Download Build Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) task to build definition to download the
  artifact of previous build. You also can call [Builds REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#get-build-artifacts) through
  PowerShell to get build artifacts.

If above not help you, you can share your project architecture, so that we could provide  a more accurate answer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried Download Build Artifacts but I get the error `Failed in getBuildId with error`. Do you know why?